# Remote Yum mirror

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, repository

I have a bunch of remote computers that must be updated to the most recent packages for RedHat 4 and RedHat 5.  I am using mrepo to mirror the RHN packages, however the remote computers do not have an internet connection.

Because of this I have to update the mirror server that is part of the remote computers with a dvd.  This is to cut down shipping costs to just a dvd.

I am attempting to script this so I can fit all of the new packages on a CD or a DVD.  I send updates about once or twice a month depending on package requirements.

So my question is, is their a good method to do this so that the only things transferred are the new packages?  I wish I could just use rsync.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what about a diff of your directory structures? Generate a directory listing of your remote mirror and your local system and transfer only the new files to the CD/DVD.

Comment: Only issue with this I'm not sure how i would get a listing of the remote mirror since they do not have access to the internet.